# How I use BeautifulSoup in flutter

Tags: python, ios, flutter, dart, beautifulsoup

The main thing is that now i can use it on the Python, but i can't do in Dart ,Can anyone convert the Python side of the code to Dart?
[image]

I tried to do like in this solution https://github.com/mzdm/beautiful_soup/blob/master/lib/src/bs_soup.dart

But this's result I got, it's error
[image]

[image]

Idk the syntax in dart

Example Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';  // สไลด์ภาพ
import 'package:fluentui_system_icons/fluentui_system_icons.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; // ควบคุมการหมุนจอ
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http; // เชื่อมต่อกับฐานข้อมูล
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
import 'package:flutter_staggered_animations/flutter_staggered_animations.dart';
import 'package:beautiful_soup_dart/beautiful_soup.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}


class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final List<String> imageList = [
    //image data
    'https://www.matichon.co.th/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/บิ๊กป้อมพักสายตาประชุมสภา.jpg',
    'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/d8/ac/3a/d8ac3ad182334ba859ceb9f70f3a64fd.jpg',
    'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/e5/4c/06/e54c060156c18cc776b4e15da2d6d035.jpg',
  ];

  //Padding Variables
  double padplanstop = 0;
  double padcoursestop = 0;
  double padrewardtop = 0;
  double padmoretop = 0;
  double paddownloadtop = 0;
  double padabouttop = 0;
  double padlasttop = 0;

  BeautifulSoup bs = BeautifulSoup('http://www.srv.ac.th/home/');
  var title = bs.findAll('a href');

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) { //ใช้ context
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, //ไม่อนุญาติให้หมุนจอ
      ]);
    return MaterialApp(           //แสดงผลบนหน้าจอ
      //ใช้ MaterialApp
      home: Scaffold(
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'http://www.srv.ac.th/home/';
    dynamic _getData() async {
    String url = (await http.post(Uri.parse('http://www.srv.ac.th/home/'))).body;
    var data = parser.parse(url);
    dom.Document html = dom.Document.html(data.outerHtml);
    List<dynamic> titleData = html
        .querySelectorAll('div.info > header > h2 > a')
        .map((e) => e.text)
        .map((e) => e.split(','))
        .toList();
    
    List<dynamic> picture = html
        .querySelectorAll('div.n2-ss-slider-1.n2_ss__touch_element.n2-ow > div.n2-ss-slider-2.n2-ow')
        .map((e) => e.data)
        .toList();

    print('${titleData}');
    print('${picture}');
    
    }
    _getData();
    setState(() {});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).